# NFT metadata not show on Opensea or Rarilble (Goerli)

Tags: solidity, nft, opensea

I am deploying a NFT collection on goerli, before going to main net and the metadata is not showing.

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x714EF69c7C39081FfAE32dafb52D475f55E2672e#code

ON etherscan the tokenURI function returns what looks to be valid data, so I don't understand why this is not showing on opensea.
returned data for token 1 is:

```
data:application/json;base64,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
```

Can any one shed any light?

I am generating the tokenURI data in the contract which has worked without a hitch in my previous contracts but here is the code in case. (full contract is at the above etherscan)

```
function eggSectionOne(uint itemId)internal view returns(bytes memory){
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            '{"name": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].name,
            '", "description": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].description,
            '", "image": "',
            eggIdToHiddenImg[itemId],
            '", "animation_url:"',
            eggIdToAnnimation[itemId],
            '", "attributes": [{ "trait_type": "Veneer", "value": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].veneer,
            '"},{ "trait_type": "Durability", "value": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].durability);
        return dataURI;
    }

    function eggSection2(uint itemId)internal view returns(bytes memory){
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            '"},{ "trait_type": "Origin", "value": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].origin,
            '"},{ "trait_type": "Temperature", "value": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].temperature,
            '"},{ "trait_type": "Buoyancy", "value": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].buoyancy
            );
        return dataURI;
    }

    function individualTokenUri(uint itemId)external view returns(string memory){
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            eggSectionOne(itemId),
            eggSection2(itemId),
            '"},{ "display_type": "number", "trait_type": "Energy Level", "value": ',
            Strings.toString(eggIdToData[itemId].energyLevel),
            '},{ "trait_type": "Colour", "value": "',
            eggIdToData[itemId].color,
            '"}]}'
        );
        return string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "data:application/json;base64,",
                    Base64.encode(dataURI)
                )
            );
    }
```